# Solicitar que se ingrese un número N, y verificar si en el valor doble del número (2*N) se encuentra algún dígito del valor original (N)

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda porfavor, tengo el problema de que no se me ocurre como podría comparar un valor del vector 1 con los otros del vector 2, y luego el otro valor del vector 1 con los otros valores del vector 2, ya que en mi for compara las mismas posiciones pero no solo uno con el resto.

Por ejemplo: N = 234 2*N = 468

La respuesta del programa deberia ser 'SI', ya que el digito 4 del número 2*N se encuentra en el número N.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector <int> v = {};
    vector <int> v2 = {};
    int N, dobleN,lon1=0,lon2=0;

    do{
    cin >> N;
    }while(N<0);

    dobleN = N*2;

    while(N!=0){ 
        int digito = N % 10;
        lon1++;
        v.push_back(digito);
        N /= 10;
    }

    while(dobleN!=0){
        int digito2 = N % 10;
        lon2++;
        v.push_back(digito2);
        dobleN /= 10;
    }
    int posi = 0; \\Este contador me suma las repeticiones

    for (int i=0; i<lon2; i++) {
        for (int j=lon1; j>0; j--){
          if (v[i] == v[j]){ \\compara posición con posición
             posi ++;
          }
        }
    }


    if (posi > 1){
        cout << "SI";
    }
    else{
        cout << "NO";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer error que tienes es que estás almacenando todos los dígitos en el mismo vector:

```
while(N!=0){ 
    int digito = N % 10;
    lon1++;
    v.push_back(digito); // <<--- v
    N /= 10;
}

while(dobleN!=0){
    int digito2 = N % 10;
    lon2++;
    v.push_back(digito2); // <<--- v
    dobleN /= 10;
}
```

Cuando lo que de verdad necesitas es guardar los dígitos del número `dobleN` en `v2`:

```
while(dobleN!=0){
    int digito2 = N % 10;
    lon2++;
    v2.push_back(digito2); // <<--- v2
    dobleN /= 10;
}
```

El segundo problema lo tienes al comparar los valores. Como ahora cada número está en un vector diferente, compararlos es bastante sencillo usando dos vectores:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j=0; j<v2.size(); j++){
        if (v[i] == v2[j]){
           posi ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Nota que para las iteraciones no estoy usando `lon1` ni `lon2`. El contenedor `std::vector` es capaz de decirme en todo momento cuántos elementos está almacenando. Si te puedes ahorrar una variable, hazlo.

Lo de `size_t`, este tipo es realmente un alias de `unsigned int` en 32 bits y de `unsigned long long` en 64 bits. Los índices negativos no son válidos, luego el contenedor `std::vector` usa realmente tipos `unsigned` para los índices. ¿Le puedes pasar un entero? sí, pero te acaban saliendo warnings y lo ideal sería que nuestros programas no tuviesen ni un solo warning (de hecho hay una opción en los compiladores para que los warnings sean tratados como errores y hagan que la compilación falle)

Por cierto, desde C++11 (estándar que vió la luz hace 10 años) tienes a tu disposición un nuevo tipo `for` que deja el código más limpio:

```
for (int d1 : v)
{
    for (int d2 : v2)
    {
        if (d1 == d2) posi++;
    }
}
```